# Google Oauth integration in Chrome extension email issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm building Chrome extension with Google Authentication. I created app in google console and get the client ID. This is included in `manifest.json` file. I need to get the email address of authenticated user.

In script I used following code to get the user details.

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    interactive: true
}, function(token) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

    x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=' + token+'&alt=json&prettyPrint=true');
    x.onload = function() {
    console.log(x.response);
    };
    x.withCredentials = false;
    x.send();
});
```

I received response as:

```
{
  "id": "108585013132758765",
  "name": "Sankar",
  "given_name": "Sankar",
  "family_name": "Gowri",
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/108585013132758765",
  "picture": "xxxxxx",
  "gender": "male",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

But I didn't receive email address in this response.

If I use following url getting cross origin error:

```
x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email?access_token=' + token+'&alt=json&prettyPrint=true');
```

How to allow cors?

Comment: Include `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` in the `scopes` section of the `oauth2` entry of the `manifest.json` file. You could also try adding `identity.email` to `permissions`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Tried with your suggestions but still not get response.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the user info endpoint to return the email address of the user to you.  You must have requested the email scope when you authenticated the user.

Comment: Added email scope. BUt it's not coming.

Comment: I added scope in manifest.josn file and google app console also

Comment: Please include your authentication code in your question.   And make sure that you are requesting access from this user again.    You need to see the consent screen again to be sure its picking it up